# Relating CSS stylesheet

Tags: html, css

İ have already searched for a similar topic and failed on finding it. The problem i'm having is about relating my HTML file with the CSS file. Before reading the code, please notice that the two sheets are on the same file and the names are properly written. It would be appreciated if you could help me notice why it doesn't work.

Also, if I've done anything wrong, please don't hate.

Here is the code:

```
    <html>
    <head>        
        <title>My First Website</title>  
        <meta charset="utf-8" />  
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Style.css"> 
    </head>
```

Thank you in advance!

Comment: so what is your question ??

Comment: you mean to link you css file to your html page ? 

if yes : `<link href="mystyle.css" rel="stylesheet" />`

Comment: Your code is valid. What's your problem?

Comment: That should work fine so long as your HTML file and CSS file are sat in exactly the directory. If the CSS is in a child then put the path like this `/subfolder/style.css` and if it's in parent `../folder/style.css`

Comment: What makes you think it doesn't work? Does the CSS not take effect? Are you sure it's not a problem with the CSS rules?

Comment: Thank you for the positive feedback but it just doesn't work. Oh well. Let me show you the full code, but please don't make fun of me=

Comment: Thanks but it just doesn't work. Oh well :) Thank you!

Comment: You'll have to show the full code (full HTML file + CSS) if you want to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly try opening up your html file in the browser. And then do inspect element. See if you can see your Style.css in the css list populated.

If you cannot access that that means either the path of your css is not correctly mentioned in the html or there is some issue with the spell if css file.

Answer (score -2):

There is nothing wrong with your code, however you should ensure that the .CSS file is in the same directory or use dynamic references for the files. This is done by simply adding a .../CSS FILE/Styles.css for example :)